# Standard error for different distributions

Tags: standard-error

I'm trying to estimate the standard error of the mean for measurements sampled from an unknown distribution. Wikipedia says:
The standard error of the mean (SEM) can be expressed as:

$$    \bar{\sigma}_x   = \frac {\sigma }{\sqrt {n}}$$

where

```
σ is the standard deviation of the population.
n is the size (number of observations) of the sample
```

I was wondering if this results holds for all distributions of our random variable $X$.

In the following post, it is implied that for estimates of the standard error in higher moment (variance, skewness), the estimate is/might be dependent on the distribution:

[What is the standard error of the mean of an exponential distribution of the form $Ae^{Bx}$ with N measurements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36048/what-is-the-standard-error-of-the-mean-of-an-exponential-distribution-of-the-for).

Specifically, when can we use:
$$SE_{\bar{σ}^2} = σ^2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}$$

Is there a certain textbook/easy paper you recommend for these kind of questions?